# How to load all dependencies in angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, webpack, npm-install

I have quite a big angular application. I am installing all packages using npm install and I am loading them manually in `index.html` file, for example:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

In similar way I am loading other files (controllers, services, etc), for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.module.js"></script>
```

What is the best way to load all necessary files without importing them manually (there are lots of js files in my project)? Is there a good tutorial on how to do it? I can't find any easy and nice solution.

Comment: Webpack does that automatically.

Comment: Use bundlers like webpack or task runners like gulp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Webpack you can easily achieve this and advantage of using this is you can use with any of these grunt, gulp, bower whatever you have used in your web app.

This will generate build for you too.

[webpack using grunt](https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-grunt.html)

[webpack using gulp (archive.org copy from 2017)](https://web.archive.org/web/20171224064733/https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-gulp.html)

[webpack using bower](https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-bower.html)

And simplest example of implementation is here  [example](https://gist.github.com/escapedcat/9cdbabd0472646cc6cef)

Answer (score 0):

Using Gulp Or Grunt for build would autogenerate and add imports to index.html.explore https://www.keycdn.com/blog/gulp-vs-grunt/ this would answer your query.